What is the difference between the SPI master shorting MOSI and MISO and connecting an SPI slave?
According to the SPI protocol, communication must be between one master and one slave, but when I short-circuit MOSI and MISO, the SPI mater can also send and receive data normally. When I connect an SPI slave, communication is also normal. I'm curious about the difference between them.
If I test the SPI master with MOSI and MISO short-circuited and there is no problem, can it be proved that the SPI master code has no problem with transmission? In other words, there is no problem in testing the SPI master when MOSI and MISO are short-circuited. It can only prove that there is no problem?
My processor is A40i, armv7 architecture, and my operating system is linux.

As opposed to--? What platform is this on? SPI is a hardware communication scheme, it has no relation to Linux so it's not clear what you are doing, where, or how. When wouldn't communication be "normal", and what qualifies as "normal"? Finally, what is the nature of the received data? How does it compare with the transmitted data? Does this tell you anything about the two connections described?

Shorting mosi to miso will result in bus contention or a loopback, don't short it, you could overdrive pins

A "loopback" connection means that the SPI master will read back whatever it writes. This is not generally very useful, the master already knows that information.
As a troubleshooting mechanism it can be useful but there are limitations you should be aware of.

It won't tell you if you have reversed MOSI and MISO
It won't tell you whether the Clock and chip select lines are functional.

Still if you have used other means (such as an osciliscope) to verify that the clock, chip-select and MOSI lines are behaving in a sane manner it can be a useful test to check that the MISO line is operating correctly.

If you short MOSI to MISO, your MISO line will be seeing whatever you’re transmitting on MOSI as a loop back. This may or may not matter to you, depending on the behavior of your attached slave.
Temporarily shorting MOSI to MISO for loopback could be useful as a sanity test for SPI driver bringup. But if you're doing this for work, I would convince your team to invest in a SPI analyzer or a 'scope with SPI protocol analysis capability. Then you can really see what's going on.
Anyway, the reason why it 'just works' in your case with MISO and MOSI shorted and with the slave also attached is probably two things:

your master is tristating MOSI right after the first byte
your slave doesn't start driving data onto its SO (master MISO) until the second byte

Since the data being driven is separated in time, master MOSI isn't clobbering the read data on slave SO (master MISO).
To make sure, you should check that more thoroughly with a scope; and also carefully review your slave device datasheet against your microcontroller reference.
That said, most SPI designs don’t tie MISO to MOSI. This avoids the MOSI / MISO clash.
As to why you might want to tie MOSI to MISO, the only reason is to support 3-wire SPI to reduce pin count. 3-wire SPI shows up with sensors, digipots and other low-pin-count devices. Again, this needs special review and attention to MOSI / slave SO tristate behavior.
In contrast, if you intend to use SPI memories like EEPROM or Flash, there's a very strong reason why you don't want to tie SPI MOSI to MISO: these memories support 2-bit and 4-bit SPI mode:

2-bit SPI redefines MOSI and MISO as bidirectional data D0 and D1
4-bit (quad) SPI brings in two more pins (HOLD and WP) and redefines them as bidirectional D2 and D3

The 2- and 4-bit modes give higher I/O bandwidth, especially useful if your system uses SPI Flash as a boot device or mass storage.

If you jumper MOSI to MISO, and tranfer a byte, you receive the same byte back you just transmitted out.
If you have an actual chip connected there instead, when you transfer one byte to the chip, the chip sends some other byte back to you.

If I test the SPI master with MOSI and MISO short-circuited and there is no problem, can it be proved that the SPI master code has no problem with transmission? In other words, there is no problem in testing the SPI master when MOSI and MISO are short-circuited. It can only prove that there is no problem?

If you short circuit MOSI and MISO, and you can receive what you transmit out, the hardware loopback proves there is no problem transmitting or receiving, and you should then also see that when you disconnect MOSI from MISO that you do not receive back same data you are sending out which proves the short circuit does really does a good loopback test.

It sounds like there is no problem in sending and receiving test data by short-circuiting MOSI and MISO, but it doesn't seem to prove anything.

@justastudent It does, by removing the short, you fail to receive what you sent which proves the short worked.

What you're describing is normally called loopback: connecting a device's transmit outputs to its own receive inputs.

Loopback is useful to test the connections between the device and the target if that connection is unreliable. For example, if connection goes through cables or a network. The loopback should be applied at the furthest point possible from the device so as much of the unreliable connection is tested.

Loopback is of no justifiable use in a reliable system (except sometimes in development, if things are going badly). There's nothing to prove in a test, the link is reliable.


Loopback is of no use for your MCU bus master of its SPI port. The MCU IC and soldered pins will be reliable unless you have serious production problems. The SPI port will just return data the MCU already had.
Like all communications systems, SPI is used to communicate data that the device doesn't have. Which is why you'd connect an target IC to the other end of the SPI bus in the first place: to read and write data with it.
And if you have an SPI target IC connected and you short its MOSI and MISO pins, you just stop the target IC doing its job.
